# My google map won't load even though my function is in the global scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am having a bit of an issue getting a google map to display on my page. I looked up the answer and found something similar that pointed me on the right track (making my function globally accessible) but after I did that, I still receive the following error [image: Error Message]

I'm not exactly sure what I've done wrong here. Below is my code:

**HTML**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Dateandtime</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/foundation.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="columns small-12">
            <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://carter3689.tumblr.com/">Blog</a></li>
            </ul>   
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">

    <div class="columns small-12" id="map" style="height:100%"></div>

    </div>


    <div id="map"></div>
<script src="js/maps.js" ></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBZMmJXCp7-bYmXDcd-a6UFWi9mBVAPy4s&callback=initMap" async defer></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript**

```
    var map;
window.initMap = function() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
    zoom: 8
  });
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: are you sure that you load the maps-API **after** `js/maps.js` ?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Yes, I apologize...I didn't grab the entire HTML code before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create an initMap function rather than assigning a function to window.initMap.  Like this:

```
function initMap()
{
     ...
}
```

See example at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple

Comment: ** Update** I found out that my file had been saved outside of my project folder. Once I placed it into the correct folder I no longer got the error...though it still doesn't show on the page. I'm thinking it may have something to do with the height?

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone...the issue was the height